# Sharepoint 2010 Web Services - System.Web.Extensions.dll not found

Tags: .net, sharepoint, gac

I am trying to upload docs to Sharepoint (2010) using a simple C# console app, via the Copy web service.

Sometimes it works, but I get intermittent failures. Viewing the http response through Fiddler, I can see that the error I'm getting back is:

```
The given assembly name or codebase, 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll', was invalid.
```

The pattern is not totally random... it might work OK for a few hours, and then start failing continually for a period of time.

Does anyone have any ideas:

- Why this error might be occurring
- Why the problem is intermittent (the Sharepoint admins inform me that there's only one server, no load-balancing, etc).

Many Thanks!

Comment: do you have .net 3.5 sp1 installed? what is the target platform for your project?

Comment: Hi - the client does... but I guess that's not really relevant here! I'm not a sharepoint admin, but I will ask the sharepoint team to confirm that the server has SP1 installed.

Comment: Nobody have any suggestions? The sharepoint admin tells me that when the error occurs, he sees "Access Denied" in the logs. So he thinks it's an authentication issue on my end. But I seriously doubt this is the case, seeing as the invalid DLL error is clearly originating from the server.

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't address this specific problem, but did solve a problem I had with Sharepoint 2010 **Lists.asmx** that manifested as

```
The given assembly name or codebase, 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll', was invalid.
```

(Searching for that error message led me here.)

I used a test project as a scaffold to get my service client connecting successfully and develop the query code. Once that was all good, wired it up to the actual application and  added `<system.serviceModel>` elements to the application's `.config` files.

However, in doing so I renamed the bindings in all `.config` files to conform to the project's naming conventions. This caused requests to fail with the error message above.

After searching the project I found that the generated files `configuration.svcinfo`, `configuration91.svcinfo` and `Lists.wsdl` contained references to the old, default binding names. After updating these, everything worked.

Note that if the service references are updated, these binding names will reset. In this case, the service reference will not need to be updated as it's near end-of-life. But in most cases, editing generated code should be avoided.

**TL;DR:**

- **This error message may be triggered by misconfigured bindings on the client.**
- **Make sure your binding names are consistent across generated code and config files.** The easiest way to do this is to leave them as default.